# How to create a release for new downloads only, not for upgrades?

Tags: android, google-play, release-management, google-play-console

I want to create a new release of Android product (an updated version, actually) but I want this version to be available for ALL fresh installs and not for updates.

Especially because the updated version has important improvements mostly for first-time users and I don't want to bother existing users too early.

Neither open/closed tracks nor staged rollout meet this criterion.

I have enough fresh daily installs to estimate the effect of the updated code, then release further updates to extend the userbase.

As an option, it would be acceptable if "staged rollout" would provide a checkbox like "make available for all new installs".

Any more ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The whole Android/Play model is designed around the same software being available for new users and for existing users. So there is no easy way of doing this. There is also a negative cost you may not have considered. New users will often reach out to existing users to help them when they get stuck. If you make the experience different, then this help method (whether via online forums or face to face) breaks.

If I absolutely had to do this, there are two options I would consider.

- Option 1: Use a product like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) to dynamically change the code for different users. That way you could do the configurations on the firebase servers, and still only ship one version of your app
- Option 2: Release a new package name (Application id). That way new users would by definition get a new product. You could even give them different descriptions, store listings and screenshots

Each of these has various difficulties, but many of the same difficulties would apply if Google Play tried to launch a service which gave different apps to new users.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I understand the point and agree with you. Although, from the perspective of the "Staged Rollout" concept, I see no problem to provide an option like "Also apply for all new installs" in addition to the percentage value. This should not break the general idea of staged rollouts nor raise issues described by you.

Comment: If you changed only staged rollout it would change the statistical validity of the test. New Installs are biased towards users who have bought new phones, hence biased towards newer models. If staged rollout only shipped to new installs, your 1% test for stability in staged rollout wouldn't properly test older devices, and you might roll out thinking something was safe when it broke old phones